# Double entendres in a 16th century Neapolitan song ("Chi la gagliarda")

Tags: meaning, regional

Here's the text of a Neapolitan song that was first published in 1551, along with what I understand from it in English:

```
Chi la gagliarda donna vo' imparare,    | Ladies, who wants to learn the galliard,
Venit' a nui che simo mastri fini,      | Come to us, who are shrewd masters,
[Che de ser' e de matina                | Who from evening until morning
Mai manchiamo di sonare:                | Never stop playing:
Tan tan tan tarira, tan ti ru ra.]

Provance un poco                        | Try a little bit,
ca 'nce vuoi chiamare.                  | because you'll want to scream;
A passa dieci volte che salimo.         | After ten steps, we jump.
[Che de ser' e de matina...]

Chi la gagliarda donna vo imparare,     | If you want to learn the galliard
sotto lo mastro el bisognia stare       | You'll have to stay under the master.
[Che de ser' e de matina...]

A che e principiante li vo dare         | To the beginners I'll give
Questo compagnio ch'a nome Martino      | This companion, called Martino.
[Che de ser e de matina...]
```

The music score archive IMSLP [has this](https://imslp.org/wiki/Chi_la_gagliarda_(Donato%2C_Baldassare)) to say about the text:

```
A fine mid-century villanella with ribald double-entendres.
```

I can see innuendo in two phrases: "ca 'nce vuoi chiamare" (apparently the lady screams because dancing lessons are so enjoyable) and "sotto lo mastro el bisognia stare" (obviously). Is there anything else? What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: While I'm not sure about the interpretation of _chiamare_ (I'd read it just as “call (the teachers)”, but I'm not an expert in 16th c. Neapolitan), I'd say that quite explicitly _'e principiante_ are the virgins (see _la giovin principiante_ in Leporello's catalogue aria in _Don Giovanni_), and the companion to be “given” them is not too mysterious either.

Comment: I am no 16th century dialect expert, but I would note a few things: imparare is also used in the south as to teach, line in _nessuno nasce imparato_ (no one is born with all the knowledge). Seen this way _Chi la gagliarda donna vo' imparare_ might sound _to those who want to teach the vigorous woman_ or _if you want to tame the strong woman_.
_ca 'nce vuoi chiamare. A passa dieci volte che salimo_ to me sounds like this: _if you want to call us, stroll around ten times and we will come upstairs_. In fact _ca_ is not like modern Italian _che_. In dialect it might read _since_ or _if_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the beginning of the text, *Chi la gagliarda donna vo' imparare* is wrong. The text says:

***Chi la gagliarda, donne,  vo' imparare*,**

*donne* plural and vocative, as in the English translation.

(See https://www.sba.unifi.it/upload/scienzesociali/eventi/voci_parole_immagini.pdf or http://www.alphabeto.it/corale_vannucchi/spartiti/Donato-ChiLaGagliarda.pdf)

*La gagliarda* is a dance: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliarda.

> I can see innuendo in two phrases: "ca 'nce vuoi chiamare" (apparently
> the lady screams because dancing lessons are so enjoyable) and "sotto
> lo mastro el bisognia stare" (obviously). Is there anything else? What
> am I missing?

Ladies don't scream, the man who sings the song says: "*Se ci vuoi chiamare, prova e dopo dieci  volte veniamo, saliremo a casa tua (salimo)(If you want, call us, try and we come upstairs to you*)"

All the song is a double entendre, not specific lines, a sexual double sense lays underneath all the song:  the dance also can be interpreted in a sexual sense, the masters can be interpreted as  masters of love, also for 'beginner'  young women, for whom there is  'the companion Martino' (another possible sexual allusion), and the masters  go upstairs to the women,  and they 'play' all the night, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I am no 16th century dialect expert, but I would note a few things:

Imparare is also used in the south as to teach, as in the idiom *nessuno nasce imparato* (no one is born with all the knowledge).

Seen this way, *Chi la gagliarda donna vo' imparare* might sound *to those who want to teach the vigorous woman* or maybe even *if you want to tame the strong woman*.

The line *ca 'nce vuoi chiamare. A passa dieci volte che salimo*, to me sounds like this: *if you want to call us, stroll around ten times and we will come upstairs*.

In fact *ca* is (still) not like modern Italian *che*. In dialect it might read *since*, *because* or *if*.

Lastly, the *companion called Martino*, might hint to what is usually given to a woman skipping a formal introduction.